# conditional formating on "wrong" formulas

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a pretty large Spreadsheet with a lot of worksheets and a lot of cells with formulas. Sometimes there are errors in the formulas and I want to find them with conditional formatting.

All the Formulas are by row so for example

`=IF(BI7>0;'mm-1'!Z7/(BI7*($J7/12));"")`

as you see its the 7th row on all worksheets.

What I would like to do is get a conditional formatting if part of the formula is referencing on the wrong row. This way its easier for me to find the wrong cells.

Tried googling this and searching here but cant find the right solution.

Comment: had to delete some values and the formatting is of:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MtOVTWUUMKzhrYst-JOmZL2mSW7-6VUjJyFECsXNTKc/edit?usp=sharing

in this part its the formulas from J to AK
(i havent designed this but i have to manage it, rewriting all would be a huge time invest i currently dont have, there are around 20+ Worksheets like this)

Comment: Your formulas are a mess :) I suggest that instead of trying to find errors with conditional formatting, remake them with arrayformulas, so 1. you don't have to check if they're correct 2. you don't have to manually add whatever is being worked on.